# Make text under collapse not move on toggle hide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get the p text to not move when i toggle the hide show of the text? First time using collapse and similar things, tried with different position values but none seem to work.

```js
$('.testver a i').on('click', function (e) {
            var currTarget = $(this).closest('a').data('target').substr(1);
            $('#leftpanel').find('[id^="demo"]').not(currTarget).collapse('hide');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="leftpanel">
<div class="testver">
<h1>Title</h1>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
<i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
<i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
</a>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix nihil voluptatibus in, aeque zril ut quo, habemus scripserit cu duo. Mel id debitis mediocritatem. Pro ex accumsan abhorreant. Esse mentitum expetendis id eam, id mel novum legimus.
</div>
<hr>
</div>

<div class="introus">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix nihil voluptatibus in, aeque zril ut quo, habemus scripserit cu duo. Mel id debitis mediocritatem. Pro ex accumsan abhorreant. Esse mentitum expetendis id eam, id mel novum legimus.</p>
                      
 </div>
```

Comment: Instead of collapsing the element with JavaScript, have you considered changing the CSS `opacity` of the element that you wish to hide? This would keep the element in place while making it effectively hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need the bottom paragraph not to move when toggling the top paragraph. If that's the objective, then you could do this several ways but the results are the same:

**jQuery** or...

> ```
> $('p:last').css({
>     'position': 'absolute',
>     'bottom':0
> });
> ```

**CSS** or...

> ```
>  p:last-of-type {position:absolute; bottom:0}
> ```

**HTML**

> ```
>  <p style='position: absolute; bottom:0'>CONTENT</p>
> ```

To prevent overlapping of text, use height percentages (or vh) instead of pixels. In this Snippet I added these rules for paragraphs:

> ```
>  p {max-height: 20vh; overflow-y:auto;}
> ```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.testver a i').on('click', function(e) {
  var currTarget = $(this).closest('a').data('target').substr(1);
  $('#leftpanel').find('[id^="demo"]').not(currTarget).collapse('hide');
});

$('p:last').css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'bottom': 0
});
```

```css
p {
  max-height: 20vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="leftpanel">
  <div class="testver">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix nihil voluptatibus in, aeque zril ut quo, habemus scripserit cu duo. Mel id debitis mediocritatem. Pro ex accumsan abhorreant. Esse mentitum expetendis id eam, id mel novum legimus.
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="introus">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix nihil voluptatibus in, aeque zril ut quo, habemus scripserit cu duo. Mel id debitis mediocritatem. Pro ex accumsan abhorreant. Esse mentitum expetendis id eam, id mel novum legimus.</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: There is a  problem with making the text absolute.. first is that the text overlaps with everything on the website, and since its absolute i dont know how im going to get the text in place so that its places all the way below everything. And the second is that im going to have alot of other elements below this collapse so another solution than making everything absolute would reallly help!

Comment: Agreed, I believe I have another idea involving transition and height...

Comment: Would love to test it, are you trying to get it to work or? Just write here asap u get an idea and i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by just doing a div wrap of the collapse,toggle and setting a set height and width of it and nothing is moving around and all is good!